# How do I call my non static function from another class without making a new instance of class? - React Native Router Flux

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I render a right bar button in the router file, when it is tapped I want to call a function from another class that saves the data. It can't be a static method because it needs to access "this" property. If I declare a new instance of the class it won't have a the correct data. So what am I supposed to do?

Navigation screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Router, Scene, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import NewUserScreen from './NewUserScreen';
import AddMealScreen from './AddMealScreen';

export default function App() {

  return (
   <Router>
     <Scene key="root">
      <Scene key="newUser"
      component={NewUserScreen}
      title="App"
      initial
      />
      <Scene
        key="addMeal"
        component={AddMealScreen}
        title="Add Meal"
        renderRightButton={() =>(
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => AddMealScreen.saveMeal()}>
              <Text>Add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
        />
     </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Add Meal Screen:

```
export default class AddMealScreen extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state={
      mealText: '',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput style = {styles.mealTextField} 
        placeholder = "Meal"
        onChangeText={(mealText) => this.setState({mealText})}
        />
        </View>
    );
 }

  saveMeal = async () => {
     await data.saveString('meal', this.state.mealText)
     await data.getStringData('meal');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call child component function by using **ref**

you are using functional component therefore, you have to use **useRef** hook

**Code:**

Navigation screen:

```
import React, { Component, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const _AddMealScreen = useRef();

  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="newUser" component={NewUserScreen} title="App" initial />
        <Scene
          initial
          key="addMeal"
          component={() => <AddMealScreen ref={_AddMealScreen} />}
          title="Add Meal"
          renderRightButton={() => (
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => _AddMealScreen.current.saveMeal()}
              >
                <Text>Add</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this._AddMealScreen')"

Comment: @George can you try this this._AddMealScreen.current.saveMeal()

Comment: @George can you tell me the log for onPress={() => console.log(this._AddMealScreen)}

Comment: Undefined is not an object, can't get console log.

Comment: @George I have updated my answer now you can test. it was giving undefined because we were trying to use ref in functional component

Comment: Apologies, I assumed it did that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated since it uses `this` it cant be a static method, but not only, since it use `this` you don't need just *an instance* but you strictly need **the rendered instance**. You can achieve it through `ref`.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
        <Scene key="newUser" component={NewUserScreen} title="App" initial />
        <Scene
          key="addMeal"
          title="Add Meal"
          renderRightButton={() =>(
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.mealScreen.saveMeal()}>
                <Text>Add</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )}
        >
          <AddMealScreen ref={ref => this.mealScreen = ref} />
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't work, also my code isn't a class with render. I get error "The component for route 'key2' must be a React component."

Comment: I saw you are using a function component, but you should update it to a class component as you need to use `this.mealScreen` . About the error, latest doc says that `component` is a semi required: you can omit it if you add children(s) to `<Scene>`: I suggest to update 'react-native-router-flux' version and/or to check if you actually added the children as in my ansewr.

Comment: Yeah, using the class you posted doesn't work. "The component for the route 'addMeal' must be a React component."  I also don't get why 'this.mealScreen' is used, mealScreen is not defined anywhere.